# Saving document from Firestore database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a document from the database where the users can put in an email and it will pull the document and save it so I can use the document in an editing module. Here is my readUsers method

```js
Future ReadUserinDatabase(String email) async {
  Stream<List<DatabaseUser>> User = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .where('Email' == email)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => DatabaseUser.fromJson(doc.data()))
          .toList());

  print(User.map);
}
```

I will be grabbing the document ID from the returned document so I can put it in for doc to edit

```js
Future EditUserinDatabase(
    String oldemail, String newemail, String oldrole, String newrole) async {
  final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('TEST').doc('Doc ID goes Here');

  await docUser.update({'Email': newemail, 'Role': newrole});
}
```

The error that is occurring is when I print User.map it is not printing the information in the document it is printing '$user' and is not saving in a form I can use it. How do I save the document

Comment: What's your question?  Please edit the post to be more clear about what the problem is or where you are stuck.

Comment: The  ReadUserinDatabase method is not printing out any document information . it only prints out '$User' and I cant find anything wrong with the method

Comment: I suggest editing the question to explain what isn't working the way you expect.  Don't bury your debugging information in comments.

Comment: Right now, I'm trying to help you make your question more clear so that it's more likely to get an answer.  Stack Overflow has resources to help you [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  it's worth reviewing.  Many question go through a process of refinement like this.

Comment: Can you append the `User` class to the question specifically the `.map` property inside it?